# IF there are results to a command then, IF no results then for batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I need to create a batch script.

This script should be able to detect whether there are results or not.

I am using the command

```
dsquery domainroot -inactive 60
```

It tells me all of the accounts that have been inactive for 60 days.

I run the same command for 180 days and I get no results.

I run the command for 60 days and I get results.

I need to create exit codes to determine if there are or aren't any results.

The errorlevels for each of these are 0 (with and without results).

Is there any other way to detect if there are results or not. So I can get this into an IF statement.

Comment: You can parse command output to get result. Post it! About `IF`: has multiple forms, one of them using `ERRORLEVEL`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add this script to GFI after solving this issue with the script.
THe script below allows you to detect users that have been inactive for 60 days and reports the results out.

If you upload this script to GFI MAX RMM it will fail a script check and report the results to you and forward them to your PSA system if you have one configured.

Auto-generated tickets to let you know that a client did not let you know that someone has likely left the company, whats not to love.

```
@echo off
REM This batch  script was created by som3guy.
REM Cleans up any previous runs of this batch command.
cd %temp%
Del Inactiveusers.txt
echo "The following user(s) have been inactive for 60 days or more:" > Inactiveusers.txt
REM Saves a file called Inactiveusers.txt to the %temp% dir for analysis.
dsquery user domainroot -inactive 60 >> Inactiveusers.txt
GOTO Check

REM Check the filesize and sets as a variable.
:CHECK
for %%A in (%temp%/Inactiveusers.txt) do set fileSize=%%~zA
REM Determines if there is data in the file or not. And sends to appropriate Function.
IF %filesize% == 59 (GOTO NonExistant) ELSE (GOTO Existant)


:Existant
REM The below command parses Inactiveusers.txt for data and sends it to GFI via ECHO
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%temp%/Inactiveusers.txt) do echo %%i
REM Exit code for GFI
exit 1000


:NonExistant
REM No inactive users.
REM Exit code for GFI
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

this will look for at least two lines of results, change `1 2` to `1` to look for only one,
 
`dsquery domainroot -inactive 60|file.bat`
`if %errorlevel%==1 echo no results`
 `if %errorlevel%==0 echo results`


file.bat
`for %%i in (1 2) do set /p a=`
`if defined a exit 0 /b`
`exit 1 /b`

Comment: This is a great answer but is there anyway to get this all packed into a single batch file?

Comment: You may be able to wrap the `dsquery` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: I don't thhink a batchfile will provide it's own input.

Comment: I have the answer, I will post it in 3 hours once a am able to.

Answer (score 0):

Should do as you ask:

```
@echo off
dsquery domainroot -inactive 60 |find /v "" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
     echo no result
  ) else (
     echo results found
  )
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I found a way to make the script exactly what I needed.